# DHCP trouble on a WiFi network -- varies by physical location (apparently, specific to one BSSID)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dhcp, troubleshooting

Related: [Why does DHCP on this wifi network intermittently fail, and what can I do (as a client only) to fix it?](https://superuser.com/questions/1499130/why-does-dhcp-on-this-wifi-network-intermittently-fail-and-what-can-i-do-as-a)  Same network as in this question, but I think the problem is different.

I'm in a building that has a building wifi network with several access points. To be clear, I *do not* in any way, shape, or form administer this network.

Over the last few days, this network has been totally nonfunctional for me - as far as I can tell, DHCP is not assigning a usable IP address and therefore I cannot connect to the Internet. There have been brief, intermittent periods of it working OK, but not for long.

Today I was amazed to discover that this depends on location within the building. In some areas, I can connect to the network just fine. In others, which seem to have the signal at full strength, I can connect, but I cannot get an IP address from DHCP and I cannot get online. I also see that as I walk from the place where it works to the place where it doesn't work, the signal goes from moderate to weak and then suddenly to full strength.

I believe, but am not certain, that this is associated with a specific BSSID.

This makes me suspect that one of the access points is not working correctly -- is this a thing that can happen? Is there any way to circumvent this on my end (hanging out in the area where it works isn't an option), or get a very clear picture of the problem to hand to IT?

Comment: See whether you have more than one DHCP server on one subnet. That can cause this issue.

Comment: @John Is there a way to find this out myself, or is this just something to tell the IT people?

Comment: You or another person will need to look at the access point settings.  Probably the IT people should be advised.

Comment: @John I tracked it down to a specific BSSID and sent it to the IT people -- hopefully, it will be fixed soon. I wonder if there is a way to force a specific BSSID.

Comment: They would need to look at the settings on the device.

Comment: @John One other thing: Why would this problem start happening a few days ago? It was fine before.

Comment: The DHCP error needs to be researched as it would relate to a DHCP server.

Answer (score 1):

> This makes me suspect that one of the access points is not working correctly -- is this a thing that can happen?

Yes, the AP could simply have a broken Ethernet connection for a start. If the Wi-Fi network is using WPA-Personal, then the AP will seem to accept associations just fine even if it has no Ethernet uplink at all.

Or if the network is using WPA-Enterprise, it's likely that the APs use multiple VLANs (one for AP control, one for clients), and someone might have forgotten to add that particular AP to the correct client VLAN...

> Is there any way to circumvent this on my end (hanging out in the area where it works isn't an option),

Some systems (mainly Linux with wpa_supplicant or NetworkManager) let you configure a specific BSSID to connect to for a given connection profile, and/or (if I remember correctly) specific BSSIDs to *never* connect to.

On Windows or iOS or Android, you're probably out of luck.